# C# inheritance and method signatures

Tags: c#, interface, overloading

I am working on a class that needs run a different process method based on the type of object I pass in. I thought that overloading might work here, but I have a question. Lets say I have two interfaces:

```
public interface IEmail 
{
      Some properties ...
}
```

and

```
public interface ISpecialEmail : IEmail
{
     Some more properties....
}
```

and a class to process these objects:

```
 public class EmailProcessor
 {

      public void ProcessEmail (IEmail email)
      {
           do stuff;
      }

      public void ProcessEmail (ISpecialEmail email)
      {

          do different stuff
      }
 }
```

My question is, being that ISpecialEmail inherits from IEmail, are these method signatures sufficiently different to allow for overloading? My original thought is that ISpecialEmail emails would also trigger the IEmail signature because technically that interface is implemented also.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If it compiles then it should work fine. There is no way the compiler/runtime would let a single method call run two separate functions at the same time

Comment: Why don't you try compiling the program and actually seeing what happens.  You already have most of the code needed to test this.  Why didn't you try that before posting it here?

Comment: @musefan Note that it's not only a question of if there is ambiguity, but which overload will be chosen.  You do need to do more to see *if* it compiles, you need to determine which overload the compiler thinks is "best".  That said, it's still a simple thing to do; it just means you need to run it once after compiling it.

Comment: @Servy: Yeah, after posting I just thought about a "priority" article I read a while back. I imagine that would have something to say about this

Comment: I know it will compile properly, I just wasn't sure if anyone knew if it would choose the right method. Unfortunately, this is part of a web service and I have a ways to go before I can test it. Thanks for the comments though.

Comment: @musefan Well, the simple option is just to run the program.  If you want to understand why it does what it does, simply consult the C# language specs.  They are *the* source for the formal definition of method overload resolution.

Comment: Why don't you combine both ProcessEmail methods into one?

Comment: @Mike You can create a new console app with these methods, interfaces, and enough console writes to give you your answer in one or two minutes.  You don't need any special business logic mixed in to get your answer.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Assuming they do different things then separation of concerns would say they should be different methods.

Comment: Not the article I was remembering, but [this might be worth a read](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you call the methods.

For example, assume you have `Email : IEmail` and `SpecialEmail : ISpecialEmail`. If you declared a list of emails:

```
List<IEmail> emails = new List<IEmail> {new Email(), new SpecialEmail()};
```

And then ran

```
foreach (var email in emails) { EmailProcessor.ProcessEmail(email) }
```

It will call `public void ProcessEmail (IEmail email)` for *both* - because the call binding happens at compile time (i.e. it wouldn't work the way you wanted).

It would also fail if you did something like:

```
var email = GetEmail(); // returns either IEmail or IExtendedEmail
EmailProcessor.ProcessEmail(email); // Would ONLY call ProcessEmail(IEmail)
```

So, polymorphism would fail with those signatures.

However, the following would work:

```
var email = GetEmail(); // returns only IEmail
var extendedEmail = GetExtendedEmail(); // returns only IExtendedEmail
EmailProcessor.ProcessEmail(email); // Would all ProcessEmail(IEmail)
EmailProcessor.ProcessEmail(extendedEmail ); // Would call ProcessEmail(IExtendedEmail)
```

Comment: The goal is to use a factory to get the email and simply run the emailProcessor.ProcessEmail method. How would you go about enforcing polymorphism then?

Comment: @Mike Have `ProcessEmail` be a method of `IEmail`, or have enough information in just that information to process either type, and then let different implementations overload the interface members differently to achieve different behavior.

Comment: To get polymorphism to work, you would need to move the ProcessEmail() signature to be part of IEmail, and then have concrete implementations in Email / Extended email classes. However, that would mean the code for processing emails would be inside the email objects which you might not want - what @Servy said :)

Answer (score 2):

According to the C# spec (section 7.4.3)

"methods in a base class are not candidates if any method in a derived class is applicable"

`public void ProcessEmail (ISpecialEmail email)` should be the function called if an `ISpecialEmail` is passed in. Be careful about casting it down to an `IEmail`, though, as that will change the precedence. If you're combining all of the emails, both of types `IEmail` and `ISpecialEmail` into one `List` of `IEmail`s for processing, they'll all go through the `IEmail` version of the function.